# Please explain the end of John Dies at the End

Tags: title, john-dies-at-the-end

The title of the movie is *John Dies at the End*, but for some reason this doesn't happen. He dies for a short while in the middle, and then comes back, but this makes the title inaccurate, especially since the whole movie is based on the premise that the drug they take allows them to be all- knowing. So what's the deal here?

Comment: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11684/why-is-it-called-john-dies-at-the-end

Comment: Please avoid ruining movies for people by following our cardinal rule - [Don't put spoilers in question titles](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).